# Use a Factory to retrieve dependencies from database and construct a complex object

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, factory

I am currently using a factory to retrieve several objects from database and returning a complex object.

My question is, is this a valid usage for a factory?

I am using a legacy database which has no options for fanciness.

Here is a code example for demonstration purposes:

```
public class ComplexItem : IComplexItem
{
    public ComplexItem(Item item, List<ItemPart> itemParts, List<ItemComment> itemComments)
    {
        //Setter
    }
}


public class ComplexItemFactory : IComplexItemFactory
{
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;
    private ItemPartsRepository itemPartsRepository;
    private ItemCommentsRepository itemCommentsRepository;

    public ComplexItemFactory(ItemRepository itemRepository, ItemPartsRepository itemPartsRepository, ItemCommentsRepository itemCommentsRepository)
    {       
        //Setter
    }

    public IComplexItem CreateComplexItem(ItemKey itemKey)
    {
        var item = itemRepository.Get(itemKey);
        var itemParts = itemPartsRepository.GetItemParts(itemKey);
        var itemCommentsRepository = itemCommentsRepository.GetItemComments(itemKey);

        return new ComplexItem(item, itemParts, itemCommentsRepository);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is that an abstract factory?  It looks like a concrete one.

Comment: Seems like a pretty standard factory pattern to me. There is nothing really "abstract" about it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for a concrete factory not an abstract one. I changed my question... So for a Concrete Factory, do you think this is a good approach?

Comment: Looks good. Is there a reason this concerns you?

Comment: The reason I ask is that over my time as a developer I have never seen anyone use factories like this. I have started using factories more since I began using tdd and found this helpful both for tests, code readability and maintenance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this question, it feels kind of silly.
Yes there is nothing wrong with this factory.

Today ORM's would solve this problem for you...